# Minimum common denominator with Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would find the minimum common denomintor in my Pandas dataframe that looks like this example:

```
dummy = pd.DataFrame([
{'X1':1,'X2':0,'X3':1,'X4':1,'X5':0},
{'X1':1,'X2':1,'X3':0,'X4':0,'X5':0},
{'X1':1,'X2':0,'X3':1,'X4':1,'X5':1},
{'X1':0,'X2':0,'X3':1,'X4':0,'X5':1},
{'X1':0,'X2':0,'X3':0,'X4':0,'X5':1}])
```

Based on this table, I see the third line with the most products (X1, X3, X4, X5) and most sold products are X1, X3, and X5 (all of them three times). How can I find the minimum common denominater now? In this case, I would like find the combination X1, X3, and X5 as this has been sold two times (first and third line).

Thanks
Sebastian

Comment: Could you add your desired output in this data sample?

Comment: "In this case, I would like find the combination X1, X3, and X5 as this has been sold two times (first and third line)." this line looks a bit wrong. can you check the sample dataframe which you have provided?

Answer (score 1):

Use `s1 = df.apply(lambda x: sum(x), axis=0)` to get the count for each product

```
>>> s1
X1    3
X2    1
X3    3
X4    2
X5    3
```

Next, find the maximum number of products

```
>>> max(s1)
3
```

Finally, get the products which have the maximum number sold

```
>>> s1[s1==max(s1)]
X1    3
X3    3
X5    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the columnwise sum with:

```
>>> dummy.sum()
X1    3
X2    1
X3    3
X4    2
X5    3
dtype: int64
```

So we can obtain the maximum columns with:

```
sums = dummy.sum()
indices = sums[sums == sums.max()].index
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> indices
Index(['X1', 'X3', 'X5'], dtype='object')
```